# Setting Gas fees for substrate chain which has frontier integrated in it

Tags: evm, frontier, gas, polkadot-sdk

I am deploying the default smart contract in remix ide to local substrate chain using Metamask to connect with the chain.
The local chain uses frontier for EVM.

But fees comes quite high.
I want to set the fees to lower value. How do I do it?
How is the gas fees calculated by frontier.

Also, it would be great if someone could explain how data flows from remix ide to metamask to node running on computer and hits which function on the node.